# Proving that the compositional powers of a rational function are distnct.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, divisibility, rational-functions

I have a rational function, $f(x)$, and I would like to prove that for all positive integers, $i,j$, and for all rationals, $w=q/p$, such that $w \notin \{ -1, 0, 1 \}$, we have $f^i(w) = f^j(w)$ only if $i=j$ or, in other words, that the sequence $w_i=f^i(w)$ is acyclic. The superscripts here refer to composition, not multiplication.

We can reduce it to two polynomials, $\frac{f_1}{ f_2}$ in the integer variables $p, q$.

We can then show that:

1) For all $p,q$,  we have that $gcd(f_1 (p, q), f_2(p, q))$ is some power of $2$.

2) $pq|f_1(p,q) $ and $gcd(\frac {f_1(p,q)}{pq}, pq) \in \{1, 2, 4 \}$.

3) Neither $\frac {f_1(p,q)}{pq}$ nor $f_2(p,q)$ is $1$ and that at most one of them is a power of $2$.

Does this suffice to prove that the sequence  $w_i=f^i(w)$ is acyclic? Or am I missing something?

Comment: What about $x \mapsto x$ and $x \mapsto 1/x$?

Comment: The conditions rule out both possibilities for rational x. Indeed if f(x) = 1, then f_1(x) = f_2(x) from which we see from (1) that both are a power of two, contradicting (3).

Comment: If f(x) = x = q/p, then pf_1(p,q) = qf_2(p,q). From (2), we have that pq|f_1(p,q) leading to f_1(p,q)/q = f_2(p,q)/p so p|f_2(p,q). Then from (1), p is a power of two. On the other hand, pf_1(p,q) = qf_2(p,q) implies that p = qf_2(p,q)/f_1(p,q) which with (3), yields that their is some prime other than 2 dividing f_1(p,q) and this contradicts (1).

Comment: Ah, I see that you meant taking powers. I interpreted your notation as repeated function application.

Comment: It is repeated function application. Powers are trivially distinct.

Comment: I did mess up in my first comment though, I meant f_i(p,q) instead of f_i(x)